# How do I loop through a nested array in angular/Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've been searching but everything I come across is for looping in HTML, and I need to loop in a .ts.

I have an array that I need to loop over and check if the entered value matches the key. If it does, then return the values inside the array

```
data: any = {
    '1234': {
        site: 'https://example1.com/',
        path: 'uploads',
        link: 'https://example1.com/uploads',
    },
    '5678': {
        site: 'https://example2.com/',
        path: 'uploads',
        link: 'https://example2.com/uploads',
    }
}
```

I've been trying all sorts of variations on the following, with limited success. I can print the key, but I can't get at the values (site, path, link)

```
let pin = '1234';
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    if(key == pin) {
        Object.keys(key).forEach(k => {
            // I'm trying to get something like k.url so I can store it
            console.log(k.url);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In JavaScript, arrays are enclosed with square brackets (`[ ]`); objects, curly brackets (`{ }`). The question is better named "loop through nested object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only a single loop to achieve that

```
const pin = '1234';
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    if(key == pin) {
         console.log(data[key].url);
         console.log(data[key].site);
         console.log(data[key].path);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
    '1234': {
        site: 'https://example1.com/',
        path: 'uploads',
        link: 'https://example1.com/uploads',
    },
    '5678': {
        site: 'https://example2.com/',
        path: 'uploads',
        link: 'https://example2.com/uploads',
    }
}

const pin = '1234';

const properties = { ...data[pin] };

Object.values(properties).forEach(v => console.log(v));

// This will NOT throw an exception
// Using a non-existing key here
Object.values({...data['fake']}).forEach(v => console.log(v));

// This will throw an exception
// Using a non-existing key here
Object.values(data['fake']).forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

This does what you want and uses only a single loop. I used spread syntax to prevent undefined. If the key you're looking up by won't exist, an empty array will be brought back.

Comment: What is the point of spreading an object into an object? Is that code really necessary? Why not just use `data[pin]` directly?

Comment: @georgeawg `data[pin]` may return an object, it also can return a undefined if key does not exist. This will translate into `Object.values(undefined).forEach(v => console.log(v));` and that will be an exception. Using spread operator undefined will translate into an empty object which can be successfully used to loop through its values. I've updated my answer with an example to illustrate that. Thanks for good question!